# select rows using ctrl key using knockout and jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using jquery template to bind data coming from knockout obervable array like this

```
<script id="instructorTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <tr class="clickableRow">
     <td style="padding: 0px;text-align: left" >${Id}</td>
     <td style="padding: 0px;" >${UserName}</td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

Now i want to select maximum 2 rows using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. How can i achieve this?

I tried using class `clickableRow`. On clicking row i can change color to Red.

```
$(".clickableRow").live("click", function () {
  $(".clickableRow").css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
  $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
});
```

But i want to select only 2 rows using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. Also if its possible to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> key and select many rows. Just like we use windows to select multiple files. But when i will use <kbd>shift</kbd> key to select many rows then it should give me value of first and last row in that selection.

Hope its clear. How to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I want functionality just like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frankdenouter/aVVXF/) but without jqgrid

Comment: Could someone tell me why its downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Final answer after some fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/aeeZb/14/

You started well, detecting the click event on the list row. 
Now you need to distinguish between a regular click, a ctrl/cmd+mouse click, and a shift+mouse click.

Luckily jQuery provides a lot of ways to detect these with e.ctrlKey, e.shiftKey and e.metaKey.

Check out this fiddle to see how each of them works:
http://jsfiddle.net/aeeZb/

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#list li', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    // Detecting ctrl (windows) / meta (mac) key.
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)
    {
        if ($this.hasClass('selected'))
        {
           $this.removeClass('selected');
        }
        else
        {
           $this.addClass('selected')
        }                        
    }
    // Detecting shift key
    else if (e.shiftKey)
    {
        // Get the first possible element that is selected.
        var currentSelectedIndex = $('#list li.selected').eq(0).index();

        // Get the shift+click element
        var selectedElementIndex = $('#list li').index($this);

        // Mark selected between them

        if (currentSelectedIndex < selectedElementIndex)
        {
            for (var indexOfRows = currentSelectedIndex; indexOfRows <= selectedElementIndex; indexOfRows++)
            {
                 $('#list li').eq(indexOfRows).addClass('selected');  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (var indexOfRows = selectedElementIndex; indexOfRows <= currentSelectedIndex; indexOfRows++)
            {
                 $('#list li').eq(indexOfRows).addClass('selected');  
            }
        }                        
    }        
    else
    {
           $('#list li').removeClass('selected');
           $this.addClass('selected');
    }        
});
```

});

P.S: 
If you want to implement a maximum 2 row selection, you can do so by checking the current amount ( $('list li.selected').length() ) of "selected" items before marking the current selection as selected.

Comment: In your example i can only select only item using ctrl key. How to select 2 rows?

Comment: In my example, ctrl+click will add the selected item to the current selection, and shift+click will add all the items in-between the two selections (just like in windows folders when selecting files :) )

Comment: But in your case i am not able to select 2 rows using ctrl key. How to do it? Also getting error while running fiddle that $ is not defined

Comment: You can select 2 or more rows using my example with ctrl+click, or shift+click to select multiple,

Comment: Is that the behavior you expected or am I missing something?

Comment: no i cant select 2 rows using ctrl key. Have you posted wrong fiddle?

Comment: Also: which OS are you using? and what browser?

Comment: windows 7 and Internet explore 10

Comment: Oh sorry man, wasn't aware of the js fiddle IE problem, I downgraded the jquery version from the fiddle, does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/aeeZb/4/

Comment: yes my friend. Its correct. Can you quickly tell me how to read value of those cells if possible

Comment: Perfecto my friend :) If you have any link on how to do the knockout way then do let me know. This is temporaray solution for me as i want to do this in knockout way. Offcourse we still need to use jquery function for it but i will bind data using knockout. Accepting answer based on my question. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Just a small bug in your solution. When i use ctrl key to select 2 item and then remove one of item. Then use shift key to select more rows then it selects 3 items. It should select only top and lowest row when using shift key.

Comment: Let me try to understand, let's say you select "item one" and "item two", then you deselect "item two", and then shift+click "item three", you expect to see only "item one" and "item three" selected? these can be achieved using ctrl+clicking "item one" and "item three"

Comment: When i use shift key and for example select total 4 items. THen it should select Item one and Item four only. So select just 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33040/discussion-between-happy-and-ilya-merman)

Comment: when i use shift key and select multiple item then its highlighted with rec color which is ok. But why it also adds blue color

Comment: Blue color? you probably mean the default browser selection of text.

Comment: You need to add user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; to the table row so there won't be blue color

Comment: @llyaMerman were you able to find a way to do in knockout way?